# Usar uma activity/fragment em um bottom sheet

Tags: android, material-design

Eu estava dando uma estudada no Bottom Sheet, e construi algo parecido com esse do tutorial deste [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-bottom-sheets-with-the-design-support-library--cms-26031).

Fiquei na dúvida de como poderia montar algo parecido com o que faz o app do Uber. É um bottom sheet, que quando expandido me parece virar uma nova activity.

Alguém sabe como criar algo parecido ou tem um exemplo feito?

Vou deixar o [link do video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1DdoN6NLDg#t=00m26s) onde mostra o momento exato do componente que procuro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é a sua dúvida em concreto?

Comment: O efeito de transiçao do bottom sheet, onde quando está iniciado é um card com margin aos lados e quando expandido aparece uma toolbar, com um layout acima do card e sem margin @ramaral

Comment: https://uber-design-herokuapp-com.global.ssl.fastly.net/7457991f6084e7507818b227c718a800.webm algo assim

Answer (score 1):

No passo "4. Using a Bottom Sheet Fragment" do link que você disponibilizou possui um trecho de código que cria um BottomSheet sem necessidade do código visual estar presente no arquivo xml da activity onde ele irá aparecer, o método da linha 19(do passo 4 do link disponibilizado), é chamado para criar e programar sua view personalizada que será colocada no BottomSheet, você pode criar o layout desejado seguindo o passo a passo da imagem abaixo
 [image: Passo a passo para a criação do novo arquivo de layout.]

e substituir o "R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet" da linha 22

View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet, null);

Pelo nome do seu arquivo xml, e programar sua view da forma desejada, acessando os objetos pelo findViewById(), só que agora antes do findViewById(), é necessário colocar o nome da variável da linha 22, que no caso do exemplo está contentView, fincando então contentView.findViewById();

Comment: Minha duvida é mais no efeito de transiçao do bottom sheet, onde quando está iniciado é um card com margin aos lados e quando expandido aparece uma toolbar, com um layout acima do card e sem margin.

Comment: Algo assim  https://uber-design-herokuapp-com.global.ssl.fastly.net/7457991f6084e7507818b227c718a800.webm

Comment: Se o seu layout tiver um toolbar com behavior setado ele vai se comportar como no Uber